# Mysql cluster setup

Tags: 14.04, mysql, cluster

Can anyone guide me on setting up mysql cluster on 3 ubuntu 14.04 systems.
One being Management node and other 2 being Sql nodes.

Comment: What have you tried up to now? MySQL has excellent manuals and also on installing it using .DEB files: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-cluster-installation.html The fact you use Ubuntu for this has not a lot of bearing to installing it. So unless you got a specific problem related to Ubuntu I would consider this too broad to answer.

Comment: Yes. I have followed the same link which you have prescribed. But was unable to understand the Directory folders. I am a newbie, i have downloaded `mysql-cluster-gpl-7.4.12-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64` package for installation. But having many issues regarding it. I want to know a proper forum for understanding the setup of Mysql cluster.

Comment: I dont even know how to install using .DEB files. Kindly guide me. @Rinzwind

Comment: That last question is an easy one: `sudo dpkg -i filename.deb`.